# Magento 1 - Fresh 1.9.4.5 style not loading

Tags: magento-1, installation, web-setup-wizard

I just installed a fresh Magento 1.9.4.5, but the style is not loading. This is the web setup wizard:

[image: 5]

I am using PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was a right problem:

Solution. Go to your webroot and execute these two commands:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```